# How to populate <select> with ENUM values?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I want to populate an HTML `<select>` with options from an ENUM field in a MySQL database using PHP and PHP Data Objects (PDO). How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vanilla PHP implementation:

```
<select>
<?
    $result = mysql_query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$table_name.' WHERE field="'.$column_name.'"');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            foreach(explode("','",substr($row[1],6,-2)) as $option) {
                print("<option>$option</option>");
            }
        }
?>
<select>
```

PHP Data Objects implementation

```
<select>
<?
    $sql = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$table_name.' WHERE field="'.$column_name.'"';
    $row = $db->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach(explode("','",substr($row['Type'],6,-2)) as $option) {
            print("<option>$option</option>");
        }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to answer own question:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: How do you achieve the same thing in Laravel 9 where you have an enum class and want to display all the possible cases inside a select input?

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution you can use as a helper function whenever you want to get the enum values into an array to use as needed.

```
public static function getSQLEnumArray($table, $field, $db){
    $row = $db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table." LIKE ".$field)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $row['Type'], $categories);
    $fields = $categories[1];
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Great function! But I need quotes around $field:
    $row = $db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table." LIKE '".$field."')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);